# Wordpress - Assign the value return by do_shorcode() to a variable

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I am using IP2Location Tags plugin to get user's location by using IP address. I want to assign the value returned by do_shorcode() to a PHP variable. I've tried this code:

```
<?php
$region = do_shortcode('{ip:regionName}');     
echo ord($region);
?>
```

and used `ord()` to print ASCII value.
`echo ord($region);` return ASCII value 123 (i.e. { ). After getting the ASCII value of each character in `$region` I came to know that `$region` contains value `{ip:regionName}`, but on using `echo $region;` It prints `Maharashtra`.

So my question is how to get `Maharashtra` as a value in `$region;`, which will help me to compare strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this plugin replaces the keywords using filter, `do_shortcode` does nothing at all. I'm surprised you will get Maharashtra by echoing $region though but if you echo it within the_content, the filter will probably be applied.

To get the location, you can just invoke the class from the plugin and calling the necessary function like so.

```
<?php
    $ip2l = new IP2LocationTags();
    $ip2l_location = $ip2l->get_location($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
    $region = $ip2l_location['regionName'];
?>
```

`$region` will be the regionName.

`$ip2l_location` will contain the entire location value including countryCode, countryName etc. and they are stored in an associative array.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.